# Wierd behaviour of constructor property of an object

Tags: javascript

In the following code, why is 'scotty.constructor' set to 'Dog' function ?
How is the constructor property of an object set in general ? Is it set to the function that created the object using 'new' ? If so, scotty was created by 'ShowDog' and the last line should have that as output.

```js
// Dog Constructor
function Dog(name, breed, weight) {
  this.name = name;
  this.breed = breed;
  this.weight = weight;
}


// Dog Prototype
Dog.prototype.species = 'Canine';

Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  if (this.weight > 25) {
    console.log(this.name + ' says Woof!');
  } else {
    console.log(this.name + ' says Yip!');
  }
};

Dog.prototype.run = function() {
  console.log('Run!');
};

// ShowDog Constructor
function ShowDog(name, breed, weight, handler) {
  this.name = name;
  this.breed = breed;
  this.weight = weight;
  this.handler = handler;
}

// ShowDog Prototype
ShowDog.prototype = new Dog();

ShowDog.prototype.league = 'Webville';

ShowDog.prototype.stack = function() {
  console.log('Stack');
};

// ShowDog Instance
var scotty = new ShowDog('Scotty', 'Scotish Terrier', 15, 'Cookie');
console.log('Scotty\'s constructor is ' + scotty.constructor);
```

Comment: `ShowDog.prototype = new Dog();` you're setting `prototype` of `showDog` to `new Dog()` here, isn't it ?

Comment: yes I am doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object don't have an *own* `constructor` property, it's taken from their `protos`. So, without this line:

```
ShowDog.prototype = new Dog();
```

the inheritance diagram would be

[image]

Once you assign `new Dog` to the `prototype` (thus discarding its current value), the picture becomes:

[image]

and the `constructor` value (`Dog`)  is taken from `scotty.__proto__.__proto__`

To make inheritance work as intended, you have to assign the `constructor` manually:

```
ShowDog.prototype = new Dog()
ShowDog.prototype.constructor = ShowDog
```

which yields the following diagram:

[image]

Comment: How did you generated these diagrams ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee; //If you don't set Object.prototype.constructor to Employee, 
                                           //it will take prototype.constructor of Person (parent). 
                                           //To avoid that, we set the prototype.constructor to Employee (child).
```

[`MDN Reference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

---

You need to set prototype's constructor to `ShowDog` manually again else it will see the parent constructor

```
ShowDog.prototype = new Dog();
ShowDog.prototype.constructor = ShowDog
```

```js
// Dog Constructor
function Dog(name, breed, weight) {
  this.name = name;
  this.breed = breed;
  this.weight = weight;
}


// Dog Prototype
Dog.prototype.species = 'Canine';

Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  if (this.weight > 25) {
    console.log(this.name + ' says Woof!');
  } else {
    console.log(this.name + ' says Yip!');
  }
};

Dog.prototype.run = function() {
  console.log('Run!');
};

// ShowDog Constructor
function ShowDog(name, breed, weight, handler) {
  this.name = name;
  this.breed = breed;
  this.weight = weight;
  this.handler = handler;
}

// ShowDog Prototype
ShowDog.prototype = new Dog();
ShowDog.prototype.constructor = ShowDog

ShowDog.prototype.league = 'Webville';

ShowDog.prototype.stack = function() {
  console.log('Stack');
};

// ShowDog Instance
var scotty = new ShowDog('Scotty', 'Scotish Terrier', 15, 'Cookie');
console.log('Scotty\'s constructor is ' + scotty.constructor);
```